# Search for Multiple Values in JSON Object/Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following JSON Object:

```
[{"varId":13097653141527,"varValue1":"5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653174295,"varValue1":"5.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653207063,"varValue1":"6","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653239831,"varValue1":"6.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653272599,"varValue1":"7","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653305367,"varValue1":"7.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653338135,"varValue1":"8","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653370903,"varValue1":"8.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":true},{"varId":13097653403671,"varValue1":"9","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653436439,"varValue1":"9.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653469207,"varValue1":"10","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653501975,"varValue1":"10.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653534743,"varValue1":"11","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653567511,"varValue1":"11.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653600279,"varValue1":"12","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653633047,"varValue1":"5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653665815,"varValue1":"5.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653698583,"varValue1":"6","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653731351,"varValue1":"6.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653764119,"varValue1":"7","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653796887,"varValue1":"7.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653829655,"varValue1":"8","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653862423,"varValue1":"8.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653895191,"varValue1":"9","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653927959,"varValue1":"9.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653960727,"varValue1":"10","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653993495,"varValue1":"10.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654026263,"varValue1":"11","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654059031,"varValue1":"11.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654091799,"varValue1":"12","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654124567,"varValue1":"5.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654157335,"varValue1":"5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654190103,"varValue1":"11","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654222871,"varValue1":"11.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654255639,"varValue1":"12","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654288407,"varValue1":"6","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654321175,"varValue1":"8.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654353943,"varValue1":"10","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654386711,"varValue1":"9","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654419479,"varValue1":"7","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654452247,"varValue1":"7.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654485015,"varValue1":"8","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654517783,"varValue1":"6.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654550551,"varValue1":"9.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654583319,"varValue1":"10.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false}]
```

I need to be able to grab the varId value for the entry where varValue1 = "7" and varValue2 = "Standard".

Any ideas how I can do this with jquery or just vanilla JS?

Comment: Look up simple list object iteration on google. It's not that hard. ( for let i in myList ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your case, you can just loop through the array and find the matches:

```
var json='[{"varId":13097653141527,"varValue1":"5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653174295,"varValue1":"5.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653207063,"varValue1":"6","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653239831,"varValue1":"6.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653272599,"varValue1":"7","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653305367,"varValue1":"7.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653338135,"varValue1":"8","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653370903,"varValue1":"8.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":true},{"varId":13097653403671,"varValue1":"9","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653436439,"varValue1":"9.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653469207,"varValue1":"10","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653501975,"varValue1":"10.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653534743,"varValue1":"11","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653567511,"varValue1":"11.5","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653600279,"varValue1":"12","varValue2":"Narrow","available":false},{"varId":13097653633047,"varValue1":"5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653665815,"varValue1":"5.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653698583,"varValue1":"6","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653731351,"varValue1":"6.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653764119,"varValue1":"7","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653796887,"varValue1":"7.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653829655,"varValue1":"8","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653862423,"varValue1":"8.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653895191,"varValue1":"9","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653927959,"varValue1":"9.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653960727,"varValue1":"10","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097653993495,"varValue1":"10.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654026263,"varValue1":"11","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654059031,"varValue1":"11.5","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654091799,"varValue1":"12","varValue2":"Wide","available":false},{"varId":13097654124567,"varValue1":"5.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654157335,"varValue1":"5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654190103,"varValue1":"11","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654222871,"varValue1":"11.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654255639,"varValue1":"12","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654288407,"varValue1":"6","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654321175,"varValue1":"8.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654353943,"varValue1":"10","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654386711,"varValue1":"9","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654419479,"varValue1":"7","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654452247,"varValue1":"7.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654485015,"varValue1":"8","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654517783,"varValue1":"6.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":true},{"varId":13097654550551,"varValue1":"9.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false},{"varId":13097654583319,"varValue1":"10.5","varValue2":"Standard","available":false}]';

var results = [];
var searchField1 = "varValue1";
var searchField2 = "varValue2";
var searchVal1 = "7";
var searchVal2 = "Standard";
var parsed=JSON.parse(json);
for (var i=0 ; i < parsed.length ; i++)
{
    if (parsed[i][searchField1] == searchVal1 && parsed[i][searchField2] == searchVal2) {
        results.push(parsed[i]);
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

Output:

```
[{…}]
0: {varId: 13097654419479, varValue1: "7", varValue2: "Standard", available: false}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2wkvp7nu/

Answer (score -1):

Let's say that you've assigned that array of objects to `data`, you could find the object that has the `varValue1` and `varValue2` values you're after like this:

```js
var data = [{...}];
var found = data.find(item => item.varValue1 === '7' && item.varValue2 === 'Standard');
```